# TypeError: Cannot combine queries on two different base models

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms

In my django project i have 3 app, `agent`, `teamlead`, and `phone`. Both `teamleaders` models and `agents` models are of type `FieldOfficer`. A FieldOfficer has a phone. And since these phones are rotated, ie chances of a phone belonging to many FieldOfficers and viceversa are high. The `FieldOfficer` class is an abstract one and housed inside a python package separately.

Now my problems start when i try to make a `ModelForm` from the `Phone` model. I keep getting a "TypeError: Cannot combine queries on two different base models."

```
type here
```

## FieldOfficer Abstract Class

```
from django.db import models


class FieldOfficer(models.Model):
     first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 30, blank=False, null=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 30, blank=False, null=False)
    personal_phone_number =  models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True, blank=False, null=False)
    alternative_phone_number =  models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True, blank=False, null=False)    
    region = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

## agent.models.py

```
class Agent(FieldOfficer):
    teamleader = models.ForeignKey('teamleader.TeamLeader', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='teamlead')
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.first_name} {self.last_name}'
```

## teamlead.models.py

```
class TeamLeader(FieldOfficer):       

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.first_name} {self.last_name}'
```

## phone.Models.py

```
class Phone(models.Model):
    

    field_officers = models.ManyToManyField(FieldOfficer, through='AgentPhoneAssignment', related_name="phone")
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name} {self.imei}'
    

class AgentPhoneAssignment(models.Model):
    
    field_officer = models.ForeignKey(FieldOfficer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    phone = models.ForeignKey(Phone, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    ...
     # other fields

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.field_officer} {self.phone}'
```

## Create Phone form Class

```
class CreatePhoneForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Phone
        fields = []
        widgets = {
            'imei': forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'placeholder': 'Enter IMEI',
                'class': 'form-control'
            }),
            'name': forms.Select(attrs={
                'class':'form-control',
                'placeholder': 'Phone Model'
            }),
            'date_of_purchase':forms.DateInput(format='%Y-%m-%d',
            attrs={
                'placeholder':'Enter Date Of Purchase',
                'class': 'form-control',
                'type': 'date'
            }),
            'status':forms.Select(attrs={
                'placeholder':'Status of the Phone',
                'class': 'form-control'
            }),
            'field_officers':forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
                queryset=Agent.objects.all() & TeamLeader.objects.all(),
                attrs={
                'placeholder':'Select a field officer',
                'class': 'form-control'
            }),
                 
        }
```

I was hoping i could do something like

```
'field_officers':forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
                queryset= FieldOfficer.objects.all(),
                attrs={
                'placeholder':'Select a field officer',
                'class': 'form-control'
            }),
```